# Dynamically Add Columns in a SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a sql table A and i need to link it to 4(B,C,D,E) other sql tables of similar structure but different column names and types.I have two approach in mind:-

1.) **I can make a single table(F) out of 4(B,C,D,E)  and link it to main table(A) but then the number of columns will be too many and thus it will cause lots of empty spaces in table.**

2.) **I can link all the 4 tables B,C,D,E to A and that will save me empty spaces but it will make 4 foreign keys and the foreighn keys will take up unnecessary space in tables.**

Not sure of this approach but i was thinking

I can make a dynamic table to merge all 4 tables to remove the extra spaces in approach 1.

Can anyone suggest me how can i make dynamic approach work or is there any other concept i can use?

Link to the db table snapshot http://i60.tinypic.com/23hopcy.jpg.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your db structure? You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/. What do you mean by linking tables?

Comment: @Heavy here is the link to image http://i60.tinypic.com/23hopcy.jpg

Comment: What is your objective? Could you elaborate on that? Possible that the current design is not made for your problem.

Comment: @Pakspul the objective is to implement the most efficeint approach for implementing the relation between tables , reducing the empty spaces.
ps: you can refer to the diagram link which i put there.

Comment: That is also what I got from your original question, but do you want to store person metadata? You can use a many-to-many solution with a join table A -> [B,C] <- C Where [B,C] store PersonID and CategoryID. The current solution is that able to be collected with one single request? Or are you executing four queries?

Comment: @Pakspul i just need to know how to structure the tables in db-schema so as to avoid empty spaces, queries and stuff i can handle later.

Comment: You can apply something like this: http://gwb.blob.core.windows.net/winaz/11529/o_ManyToMany.png

Comment: @Pakspul okie right i've thought of this one, actually this is what my approach 2 is, but here i have 4 tables B,C,D,E so in case let's say i have taskId 1 in both B,C table then in that case it won't work, as Tasktag table won't be able to identify uniquely, i don't want to make 4 Tasktag tables.